# What does the term "carrier code" mean in a mobile phone application?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

While filling in an application I found it had divided the mobile phone into three parts as shown: "Country Code", "Carrier Code", and "Phone Number". what do these parts mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is really for your phone company, but...

As far as English is concerned, the carrier is the company that provides the phone service. I believe it is the company that owns the infrastructure (wires or whatever is used to transmit (carry) the phone signal).  "*Code*" would mean the number representing the particular company that is acting as your carrier.